# rails 4 assets not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

For months I have had bootstrap-sass working until I did a bundle update. At first the assets would not precompile because the gem had updated to version 3. I changed the gem to bootstrap-sass, '2.3.2.0' to force it to use version 2.3 because simple form does not support bootstrap 3.

Now bootstrap works in development but not production. It appears not to find the assets although capistrano deploy does a precompile.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.2'

gem 'bootswatch-rails'
```

In my js console I am seeing this which is a correct fingerprint but there are several files for application.css with different fingerprints:-

```
GET http://app.sportdata.com.au/assets/application-b0204eeff0e69f0476f26848303a9b7d.css 404 (Not Found) sports:18
GET http://app.sportdata.com.au/assets/application-a130dbe196c4f76b2ce46bc61cd2e18d.js 404 (Not Found) sports:20
```

Answer (score 3):

Open up config/environments/production.rb and make sure the following option is set to true:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Check to make sure you are not adding the public/assets directory to git. Remove the directory from git

Comment: I did that but still the same. Rebooted the server.

Comment: it makes no difference whether config.assets.compile is set to true or false.

Comment: can you make a copy of your dev version and Change the environment variable RAILS_ENV to production to see what happens. if it works then push that version to your production server

Comment: That works in production mode on my laptop but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow lost the root under server in my nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, in config/environments/production.rb, you have...

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```